# ASP.NET C# datagridview paging inside second tab when click next goes to the first tab

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, datagridview

When I tried clicking the page 2 or any page of the DataGridView inside the second tab, it will go to the first tab which includes some of my textboxes. What I would like to have is every time I clicked the next page of the DataGridView, it will show the second tab which includes the second page and not the first tab.

Can someone please help me with this?

Below are my codes:

**page.aspx**

```html
<div id="tabs-2">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable table-hover table-responsive"
        OnPageIndexChanging = "OnPaging" DataKeyNames="Employee No.">
        <RowStyle CssClass="rowStyle" />
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerStyle" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDelete" runat="server" onclick="Check_Click(this)" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle CssClass="footerStyle" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <a href="#" class="myButton btnPrev" style="color: black;">Previous Tab</a>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfCount" runat="server" Value = "0" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-warning" Text="Delete"
        OnClientClick="return ConfirmDelete();" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" />
</div>
```

**page.aspx.cs**

```
protected void OnPaging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            SetData();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems currently selected tab page resets during the page post back. This can be done pretty easily if you are using jQuery.
 You might need to store the selected tab page on tab page changed event (maybe within a hidden field) and restore the selected tab on the pageload method.